# React dynamic table with dynamic checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, dynamic, html-table

So basically I want to dynamically generate a table with checkboxes where I can give user rights to users. The thing is this has to be dynamic which in this case means that I get all available user rights via an API call and all Users with their already given rights via an API.
But I don't really know how I start with this. My first thought would be something like just a dynamic table and checkbox but I don't really know how I could like match the checkbox with the user right and the user.
I added an example table made with excel where the X replaces the checkboxes

[image: example picture]

Comment: can please add the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I didn't rly try any code so far, I just need input like how people here would do it, I don't need specific code, just like the thought-process if any1 would be willing to do that. If not I'm going to try with the dynamic table checkbox thing and then get back.